# Why didn't Reduce give me the right result?

Tags: equation-solving

My code:

```
Clear[r1, r2]; 
par[r1_, r2_] := r1 r2 / (r1 + r2); 
Reduce[{5 par[r2, 32000]/(r1 + par[r2, 32000]) == 1.8 && par[r1, r2] == 5000}, {r1, r2}]
```

with this result:

[image]

I checked it a dozen times, but I can't see why MMA doesn't give me a value for r1. So, like I always do when I'm desperate :-), I quit and restarted MMA. Copied and pasted my input. And ecco!:

[image]

Any idea what could have caused the first result?

Comment: the same input giving different answers implies that there is some (invisible) state that's different, so I think all we need here is a seer :)

Comment: @acl - maybe a feature request for version 9? :-). It sometimes happens that there are dependencies I've overlooked, but here there's just r1 and r2, and I cleared those! I can't get it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible cause for the error is a previous (and wrong) definition of `par[ ]`. For example:

```
par[r1, r2] := 5000;
Clear[r1, r2];
par[r1_, r2_] := r1 r2/(r1 + r2);
Reduce[{5 par[r2, 32000]/(r1 + par[r2, 32000]) == 1.8 &&  par[r1, r2] == 5000}, {r1, r2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

```
 par[r1, r2] := {};
```

Has the same effect :)

Comment: Looks good, er, I mean bad, you know what I mean. I checked the history of that notebook, and it has a previous definition for par[], but it's basically the same (only written as 1/(1/r1 + 1/r2) )

Comment: @stevenvh Do you have notebooks with a built-in history? You're testing a development version I must assume, since mine hasn't got that capability. I can rewrite an existing line of code leaving no trace of the original one, while the results of its execution are still alive.

Comment: @Sjoerd - I mean, I had saved the notebook before restarting MMA, and since I never delete previous calculations all my IN[]s and Out[]s were still there, only without the references. That's how the first function doesn't show In[] and Out[], while the one after restarting does. Version 8, but that's what MMA has always done, isn't it?

Comment: @stevenvh I don't think many mma share your notebook usage habits. Starting a new cell for each and every new calculation even if you only want to re-execute a calculation because you changed some variables? Even if some of the output are high memory density plots? Nah.

Comment: @Blanco - sort of like a lab notebook? It might be an ingrained habit in professions with rigorous government scrutiny of test results?

Comment: @Verbeia And that solves partially the lacking of multiple undos by enforcing habits and discipline. Now, if I only could remember where I parked my car today ...

Answer (score 1):

If you replace the number 1.8 with it's rational value 9/5 you get an answer without warnings:

```
Clear[r1, r2];
par[r1_, r2_] := r1 r2/(r1 + r2);
Reduce[{5 par[r2, 32000]/(r1 + par[r2, 32000]) == 9/5 && 
   par[r1, r2] == 5000}, {r1, r2}]

% // N
```

With the output:

> r1 == 4000000/333 && r2 == 4000000/467
>   r1 == 12012. && r2 == 8565.31

Comment: This still doesn't answer the question of what caused the first output shown...

Comment: @J.M. I coudn't reproduce the first output.

Comment: @Peter - thanks. Maybe I should have said I'm an engineer, and for engineers the result is 12000 and 8600; we don't care that much about 10 significant digits :-). (For quick calculations in my head pi is often 3. Go figure.)